# Batch generation of straight line questions with images and answers saved to disc

Tags: plotting

I'm looking for a Mathematica solution to generate (a lot of) student questions for interpretation of a straight line graph, i.e. an image of a straight line where the student should find the expression y=kx+m given the image.

Is it possible to have Mathematica to loop over say n=100 iterations and for each cycle:

1. Generate two random numbers, k and m, (let's make it integer on [-10,10] for simplicity)
2. Define a function y=kx+m
3. Plot y (with fixed, uniform, dimensions so all graphs have the same 'look')
4. Save image to disk
5. Append the answer (y=kx+m, e.g. 'y=-3x+5') to a list

and at the end save the 'answer list' to disc?

TIA

Follow up (#2). After some testing

```
Clear[y, x, k, l]
For[
 i = 1, i < 3, i++,
 k = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
 l = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
 y[x_] := k x + l;
 Print [y[x]];
 H = Plot[y[x], {x, -3, 3}];
 ImageFileName =
  "/Users/...<some-path>.../Downloads/test"  <> ToString[i] <> ".pdf"; 
 Export[ImageFileName, H, "PDF"];
 ]
```

Is the syntax good?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to start easy and I do get y(x) printed on screen but the Plot function does not seem to display. (I would like to add my code there, but I don't know how to. Found out how to add code to original post, sorry.)

Comment: Take a look at `Table` and `Map` instead of trying a For loop. `Table` will return a list of results that you can save into a variable for later export, printing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a fairly good template:

Define a function that takes an ID and returns a suitably randomized graph of a line that includes some clearly labelled points.

```
lineProblemGeneratorPointsGiven[problemIDNum_] := Block[
    {m, k, visibleDomain, shownXVals, shownPoints},
    m = RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]];
    k = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
    lineEq[x_] := m x + k;
    visibleDomain = Clip[Sort[{(-20 - k)/m, (20 - k)/m}], {-20, 20}];
    shownXVals = RandomSample[Range @@ IntegerPart[visibleDomain], 2];
    shownPoints = ({#, lineEq[#]} & /@ shownXVals);
    graphicForStudent = Plot[
        lineEq[x], 
        {x, -20, 20}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
        Frame -> True, 
        FrameStyle -> Bold, 
        GridLines -> Transpose[shownPoints], 
        Epilog -> {
            PointSize[0.015], Red, Point[shownPoints], 
            Black, Text[Style[ToString[problemIDNum], 30], {-19.5, 17}, {-1, 0}]
        }, 
        FrameTicks -> {{Transpose[shownPoints][[2]], None}, {Transpose[shownPoints][[1]], None}}
     ];
    {Rasterize[graphicForStudent, RasterSize -> 500], problemIDNum, m, k}
]
```

Now use it to generate a batch of problems:

```
my5Problems = lineProblemGeneratorPointsGiven /@ Range[5];
```

Now you want to export this so you have a folder of images and a spreadsheet of answers, so go ahead and make some directory lineProblemStorage. Include inside that one some directory imageStorage.

```
 linePicsWithID = #[[1 ;; 2]] & /@ my5Problems;
 Export[FileNameJoin[{lineProblemStorage, imageStorage, ToString[#[[2]]] <> ".jpg"}], #[[1]]] & /@ linePicsWithID
```

Now imageStorage contains the images to be given to the students. You need your answer sheet, though.

```
myAnswers = Join[{{"ID", "m", "k"}}, #[[2 ;; 4]] & /@ my5Problems];
Export[FileNameJoin[{lineProblemStorage, "answers.xls"}], myAnswers]
```

I seem to remember tests being averse to giving students labelled points when reading from graphs in order to prepare them for the real world where graphs *are only used to communicate numerical minutiae of the function in question rather than to eyeball a solution for sanity or present themes and trends*./s

If you want to be cruel and have your students strain their eyes and second guess themselves finding points that fall on the grid, you can use this generating function instead:

```
lineProblemGeneratorGridLines[problemIDNum_] := Block[
    {m, k, visibleDomain, shownXVals, shownPoints},
    m = RandomChoice[Join[Range[-5, -1], Range[1, 5]]];
    k = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}];
    lineEq[x_] := m x + k;
    graphicForStudent = Plot[
        lineEq[x], 
        {x, -20, 20}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
        Frame -> True, 
        FrameStyle -> Bold, 
        GridLines -> {Range[-19, 19], Range[-19, 19]} , 
        Epilog -> {Black, Text[Style[ToString[problemIDNum], 30], {-19.5, 17}, {-1, 0}]}
     ];
     {Rasterize[graphicForStudent, RasterSize -> 500], problemIDNum, m, k}
  ]
```